# How can i remove firefox user data folder from ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: firefox

**How can i remove firefox user data folder from ubuntu 13.04?**

My firefox is too slow whenever it get slows on my other operating system i just simply remove userdata folder but how can i remove from ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first delete your firefox **user data folder** , using following command in Terminal , you can able delete firefox user data folder:

> rm -rf ~/.mozilla/firefox/.default

Where  is the name of your profile that firefox generates random.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is simply open home folder and delete mozilla folder. When you restart firefox it will create a new profile. You will then have to reset firefox like you would if you just installed it.Some times removing some add ons will speed it up.(If you have a lot installed)